# Do not understand Truth value gap theorists' response to the Strengthened Liar

Tags: philosophy-of-logic, paradox

Truth value gap theorists assert that the Liar sentence is neither true nor false - it has no truth value. But here comes my first question:

**If we take a sentence's meaning to be its truth condition, and according to gap theorist the Liar sentence has none, doesn't this mean the Liar has no truth condition, thus no meaning? But surely we do understand the Liar's meaning, otherwise we wouldn't even be able to think about it?**

Now consider the Strengthened Liar:

SL: This sentence is not true.

According to Graham Priest, there are three possible scenarios (True/False/Valueless):

- SL is true. Then in virtue of the T-schema, SL is not true.
- SL is not true. Then either it is false, or valueless.

  If it is false or valueless, then this means SL is not true,
  thus (again by the T-schema) it is true.

So it seems that gap theorists have trouble dealing with the Strengthened Liar.

According to Tyler Burge's paper in 1979 titled 'Semantical Paradox' (excerpt attached below), there are three responses a gap theorist have. But I am having trouble understanding them:

1.

> ...simply to reject the remark that the sentence displayed is not
> true. This rationale goes: one must take seriously one's claim that
> 'true' is undefined or 'gappy' for some arguments; the Strengthened
> Liar simply seduces one into forgetting this insight.

**Priest's explanation of SL depends on SL being false or valueless is the same as SL being not true. Is this what gap theorists are trying to block? i.e. when we say SL is valueless, it doesn't mean it's not true - it doesn't make any sense to talk about SL having any truth value whatsoever**

2.

> ...to place restrictions on substitutivity of identity to block the
> move from remakring that the displayed sentence is not true to
> asserting that SL is not true.

**This one I genuinely have problem understanding: if SL is not true, surely we are justified in asserting that it is not true - what kinda restriction can we possibly impose to stop us from asserting so?**

3.

> A third response by gap theorists fixes on negation. The idea is that
> when we say of 'it is not true of itself' that it is not true of
> itself, we are using a broader sense of negation than the sense used
> in the pathological occurrence of 'it is not true of itself'.

**Again I am completely lost here; what do 'broader sense of negation' and 'pathological occurrence of :it is not true of itself"' mean?**

---

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Gap theorists do not take sentence's meaning to be its truth condition. This is not unusual, many take sentences of ethics or aesthetics to be meaningful but neither true nor false. 1. simply means that the truth predicate does not apply to such sentences, and SL is ungrammatical. Ungrammatical is not the same as "valueless" that falls under "not true", it means that ~T(SL) is not well-formed and is not to be reasoned about. 2. is hypertechnical, it would block you from replacing "this" by SL. 3. distinguishes between denying truth and asserting falsehood, which SL mixes.

Comment: 1. is implemented in [Kripke's theory](https://iep.utm.edu/par-liar/#SH3c), and 3. in [Barwise-Etchemendy's](https://iep.utm.edu/par-liar/#SH3d).

Comment: I think of it like this.  If we have a system or method for assigning truth to certain statements in a satisfactory way - then we can say, under that system, statements have the truth values given by that system.  This works for ZFC and also for more informal reasoning in many domains.  For the liar paradox or strengthened liar paradox, we don't have a system for assigning truth in a satisfactory way.  So we just don't define truth for those statements.  Then, just because "This statement is not true" is not assigned a truth value, does not mean we can assign it "true,"

Comment: ... because SL simply sits outside of any system we might use to assign truth to statements.  So it's invalid to make that deduction "it's not true therefore we assign it true."  There isn't any satisfactory system of reasoning (with SL in its domain) that we would use to justify that deduction.